# two overlaying divs with a transparent color, how to make upper one mask the lower one?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that overlap. One is a square with rounded corners such that it's a circle and the other is a long rectangle. They're at the top of the page so that they make a nice header. The circle overlaps the rectangle. I want to put buttons in there, etc. Both divs use as the background color. Note the transparency.

```
background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.2);
```

When the circle overlaps with the rectangle, naturally the colors are blended together so that the color is stronger (it's more white). Is there a way to "ignore" the bottom color since it's underneath and only have the top color be the dominant one? Will CSS blending options help me out here or do I have to pull the rectangle our and somehow plug the crack between the circle and rectangle?

```
.rectangle {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.2);  
margin-bottom:5px;
}

.circle {
width:400px;
height:400px;
top:-200px;
left:-200px;
position:absolute;
background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.2);  
border-radius:200px;
}
```

Comment: Why cant you just change the opacity on the circle?

Comment: I want the header to be slightly opaque so that my background shows up. There will always a part of the rectangle under will show up unless opacity is 1.

Comment: easiest way is just use an image then.

Comment: This sounds impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what your looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/EBX93/ - The rectangle is a div in a div. The back div has a white background, the front div has a light color. I tried :before and :after and that didn't work. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to get them to look like they're both a single object. When I had the same color with the transparency, that's when it starts looking all messed up.